# ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - JSONException Misplaced endArray

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I am making a RESTful twitter/facebook clone using Grails and AngularJS, so it's a standard user can post, user can like posts and user can follow other users.

I am using JSON object marshallers so that the attributes of the `hasMany` or the `belongsTo` of the domain class would be rendered in the JSON.

I have inserted the necessary relationships between the `User` and `Post` domain for the like feature and when I implement them in my `Bootstrap.groovy` and if i send a `GET` request to `api/posts/` everything works fine but the problem is when I implement them using a button. 
This button sends a `PUT` request to `api/posts/:id` and this goes to the `update()` method of my `PostController`. The like is being inserted into the database but if I send again another `GET` request to `api/posts` I get this error

```
....Error
|
2015-09-26 00:54:35,986 [http-bio-8090-exec-9] ERROR 
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver 
 - JSONException occurred when processing request: [GET] /restsocnet/api/posts
Misplaced endArray.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Misplaced endArray.
    Line | Method
->>  202 | value              in grails.converters.JSON
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    162 | convertAnother     in     ''
|    202 | value . . . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother     in     ''
|    202 | value . . . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother     in     ''
|    202 | value . . . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother     in     ''
|    202 | value . . . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother     in     ''
|    202 | value . . . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother     in     ''
|    202 | value . . . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother     in     ''
|    202 | value . . . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother     in     ''
|    202 | value . . . . . .  in     ''
|    134 | render             in     ''
|    150 | render . . . . . . in     ''
|     19 | index              in com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.PostController
|    198 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    118 | processFilterChain in grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter
|     84 | doFilter           in     ''
|     53 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    143 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     82 | doFilter           in com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter
|   1142 | runWorker . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

---

These are my codes

User.groovy

```
package com.patrickjuen.restsocnet

class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    static hasMany = [posts: Post, likedPost: Post]
    static mappedBy = [posts: "user"]


    User(String username, String password) {
        this()
        this.username = username
        this.password = password
    }

    @Override
    int hashCode() {
        username?.hashCode() ?: 0
    }

    @Override
    boolean equals(other) {
        is(other) || (other instanceof User && other.username == username)
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        username
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this)*.role
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
        likedPost nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
        posts lazy: false, sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'desc'
        likedPost lazy: false

    }
}



package com.patrickjuen.restsocnet

import grails.converters.JSON

//import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured


@Secured(['isFullyAuthenticated()'])
class PostController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]


    def springSecurityService

    def index() {
        render Post.list(sort: "dateCreated", order: "desc") as JSON
    }

    def save(){
        def newPost = new Post(request.JSON)
        if(!newPost.hasErrors()){
            def currentUser = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
            println currentUser
            newPost.user = currentUser
            newPost.save(failOnError: true)

//            currentUser.addToPosts(newPost)
            render (['success': true] as JSON)
        }
    }

    def show(){
        def post = Post.get(params.id)
        render post as JSON
    }

    def update(){
        def post = Post.findById(params.id)
        if(!post.hasErrors()){
            def currentUser = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
            post.addToLikers(currentUser)
            post.save(flush: true)
            render(['success': true] as JSON)
        }
    }
}
```

Post.groovy

```
package com.patrickjuen.restsocnet

class Post {

    String content
    Date dateCreated
    User user
    static belongsTo = User
    static hasMany = [likers: User]
//    static mappedBy = [likers: "likedPost"]
    static constraints = {
        likers nullable: true
    }
    static mapping = {
        likers lazy: false
    }
}
```

Bootstrap.groovy

```
import com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post
import com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Role
import com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User
import com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.UserRole
import grails.converters.JSON

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(User) {
            def returnArray = [:]
            returnArray['id'] = it.id
            returnArray['username'] = it.username
            returnArray['posts'] = it.posts
            return returnArray
        }
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Post) {
            def returnArray = [:]
            returnArray['id'] = it.id
            returnArray['content'] = it.content
            returnArray['dateCreated'] = it.dateCreated
            returnArray['user'] = it.user
            returnArray['likers'] = it.likers
            return returnArray
        }


        def role = new Role(authority: "ROLE_USER")
        def user1 = new User(username: "user1", password: "password")
        def user2 = new User(username: "user2", password: "password")
        role.save()
        user1.save()
        user2.save()

        def post1 = new Post(content: "new post number 1")
        def post2 = new Post(content: "new post number 2")
        def post3 = new Post(content: "one more ")
        def post4 = new Post(content: "i am user2 guys hehehe")
        post1.save()
        post2.save()
        post3.save()
        post4.save()

        user1.addToPosts(post1)
        user1.addToPosts(post2)
        user1.addToPosts(post3)
        user2.addToPosts(post4)
        post2.addToLikers(user2)
        post2.addToLikers(user1)
        post1.addToLikers(user1)

        UserRole.create(user1, role, true)
        UserRole.create(user2, role, true)
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

PostController.groovy

```
package com.patrickjuen.restsocnet

import grails.converters.JSON

//import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured


@Secured(['isFullyAuthenticated()'])
class PostController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]


    def springSecurityService

    def index() {
        render Post.list(sort: "dateCreated", order: "desc") as JSON
    }

    def save(){
        def newPost = new Post(request.JSON)
        if(!newPost.hasErrors()){
            def currentUser = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
            println currentUser
            newPost.user = currentUser
            newPost.save(failOnError: true)

//            currentUser.addToPosts(newPost)
            render (['success': true] as JSON)
        }
    }

    def show(){
        def post = Post.get(params.id)
        render post as JSON
    }

    def update(){
        def post = Post.findById(params.id)
        if(!post.hasErrors()){
            def currentUser = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
            post.addToLikers(currentUser)
            post.save(flush: true)
            render(['success': true] as JSON)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried removing the JSON object marshallers and it doesn't give out the error anymore but I won't be able to access the attributes of the `hasMany`. So I guess the main problem is the JSON object marshallers. Am I implementing them wrongly? Or is there an alternative to using JSON object marshallers? But yet again it works fine as I implement them in the `Bootstrap.groovy`
Also, I tried changing `post.save(flush:true)` to just `post.save()` it doesn't give out the error but the like is not being saved in the database.

---

Just in case you are interested in the JSON being rendered.
This is a `GET` request to `api/posts/`

Without JSON object marshallers

```
[
  {
    "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post",
    "id": 4,
    "content": "i am user2 guys hehehe",
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:39:10Z",
    "likers": [],
    "user": {
      "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User",
      "id": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post",
    "id": 3,
    "content": "one more",
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:39:10Z",
    "likers": [],
    "user": {
      "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User",
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post",
    "id": 2,
    "content": "new post number 2",
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:39:10Z",
    "likers": [
      {
        "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User",
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "user": {
      "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User",
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post",
    "id": 1,
    "content": "new post number 1",
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:39:10Z",
    "likers": [
      {
        "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User",
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "user": {
      "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User",
      "id": 1
    }
  }
]
```

With JSON object marshallers

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "content": "i am user2 guys hehehe",
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "user2",
      "posts": [
        {
          "_ref": "../../../..",
          "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post"
        }
      ]
    },
    "likers": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "content": "one more",
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "user1",
      "posts": [
        {
          "_ref": "../../../..",
          "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "content": "new post number 2",
          "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
          "user": {
            "_ref": "../../../..",
            "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
          },
          "likers": [
            {
              "_ref": "../../../../..",
              "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User_$$_javassist_5"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "username": "user2",
              "posts": [
                {
                  "id": 4,
                  "content": "i am user2 guys hehehe",
                  "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
                  "user": {
                    "_ref": "../../../..",
                    "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
                  },
                  "likers": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "content": "new post number 1",
          "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
          "user": {
            "_ref": "../../../..",
            "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
          },
          "likers": [
            {
              "_ref": "../../../../..",
              "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User_$$_javassist_5"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "likers": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "content": "new post number 2",
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "user1",
      "posts": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "content": "one more",
          "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
          "user": {
            "_ref": "../../../..",
            "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
          },
          "likers": []
        },
        {
          "_ref": "../../../..",
          "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "content": "new post number 1",
          "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
          "user": {
            "_ref": "../../../..",
            "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
          },
          "likers": [
            {
              "_ref": "../../../../..",
              "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User_$$_javassist_5"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "likers": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "user1",
        "posts": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "content": "one more",
            "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
            "user": {
              "_ref": "../../../..",
              "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
            },
            "likers": []
          },
          {
            "_ref": "../../../../..",
            "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post"
          },
          {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "new post number 1",
            "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
            "user": {
              "_ref": "../../../..",
              "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
            },
            "likers": [
              {
                "_ref": "../../../../..",
                "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User_$$_javassist_5"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "user2",
        "posts": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "content": "i am user2 guys hehehe",
            "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
            "user": {
              "_ref": "../../../..",
              "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
            },
            "likers": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "content": "new post number 1",
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "user1",
      "posts": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "content": "one more",
          "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
          "user": {
            "_ref": "../../../..",
            "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
          },
          "likers": []
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "content": "new post number 2",
          "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
          "user": {
            "_ref": "../../../..",
            "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
          },
          "likers": [
            {
              "_ref": "../../../../..",
              "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User_$$_javassist_5"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "username": "user2",
              "posts": [
                {
                  "id": 4,
                  "content": "i am user2 guys hehehe",
                  "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
                  "user": {
                    "_ref": "../../../..",
                    "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
                  },
                  "likers": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_ref": "../../../..",
          "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post"
        }
      ]
    },
    "likers": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "user1",
        "posts": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "content": "one more",
            "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
            "user": {
              "_ref": "../../../..",
              "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
            },
            "likers": []
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "content": "new post number 2",
            "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
            "user": {
              "_ref": "../../../..",
              "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
            },
            "likers": [
              {
                "_ref": "../../../../..",
                "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User_$$_javassist_5"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "username": "user2",
                "posts": [
                  {
                    "id": 4,
                    "content": "i am user2 guys hehehe",
                    "dateCreated": "2015-09-25T17:50:58Z",
                    "user": {
                      "_ref": "../../../..",
                      "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.User"
                    },
                    "likers": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "_ref": "../../../../..",
            "class": "com.patrickjuen.restsocnet.Post"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I haven't found any work around on this. I have tried using GSON and using deep. I think it might have something to do with the cascades but I am not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution. This code just needs to be inserted in `Config.groovy`

`grails.converters.json.circular.reference.behaviour = "INSERT_NULL"`

I saw it in one of the comments in this article http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/15/rendering-json-in-grails-part-3-customise-your-json-with-object-marshallers/